# Which File should be deleted to to remove history ? c# Cefbrowser

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

i have a cef browser and its almost ready but i observed one thing , when i search for the same website the second time it shows blue Link   on the google search egine , indidicating that i have already visited it . My question is which file  or folder i can delete to remove loacal history , and which file or folder to delete to remove loaclly saved webite login info , i am providing a code which shows that my PersistSessionCookies  and  PersistUserPreferences are enabled and the cache file location

```
PersistSessionCookies = true, // Enable persistent storage for session cookies
                
PersistUserPreferences = true, // Enable persistent storage for user preferences

string cachePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Browser Temp Files");

settings.CachePath = cachePath; 
      
settings.UserDataPath = cachePath;

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--disk-cache-dir", settings.CachePath);
```

These are the settings for cef browser also i am attaching a screen shot so that u can tell me which file or folder to delete indiviualy for history and login info [image]